# Does the 'hasNext' must be called before the 'next' if the size is known in java?

Tags: java, iterator

If the size of list is known, only call the 'next' without 'hasNext'. Is it right?

```java
final List<Integer> list = [1, 2, 3];
final Iterator<Integer> iter = list.iterator();

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i){
   System.out.println(iter.next());
}
```

Comment: You can, but using a loop like this defeats the purpose of using an iterator.

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: What is the purpose of the question? Is it "can you?" (Yes), or "should you?" (No)

Comment: Plus, `for (Integer i : list)` is much simpler.

Comment: `next()` doesn't care whether or not you called `hasNext()`; provided that a "next" item exists, `next()` will return it.  `hasNext()` is just the _typical_ way (but certainly not the _only_ way)  to determine that a "next" item does, in fact, exist.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's allowed. In your example, there isn't much point to it (you'd be better off either using `list.get(i)` or using `hasNext()`/`next()`), but it doesn't break anything.

One place where you *do* see `next()` without `hasNext()` is to get an arbitrary item out of a collection that is known not to be empty. This idiom comes up sometimes:

```java
Collection<T> myCollection = ...;
if (!myCollection.isEmpty()) {
  return myCollection.iterator().next();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If there is no next element and you still call `next()`, you'll get `NoSuchElementException`. To protect against this, you need to do a pre-check using `hasNext()`.

In your example, you already know the size and the condition `i < list.size()` is guarding you against trying to jump after the last element, so there is no point calling `hasNext()`.

We generally do:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) { //protection against jumping after the last element
    //call next()
}
```

You have done a similar thing, just the "protection" is a bit different (but valid):

```
for(... i < list.size() ...) { //"i < list.size()" is providing that protection
    //call next()
}
```

So no need to use `hasNext()` here.